# How to make specific words' occurrences in a textview clickable

Tags: android, textview, clickable, spannablestring

I need to make all the occurrences of a bunch of words, that I have in my textview text clickable

Eg. - **I have 2 names in my arraylist - Ajay and Dhananjay** 
and lets say text in my textview is ........

> `@Ajay`, `@Dhananjay`, I just had a great fight with @Vijay yesterday

now, I need to highlight only @Ajay and @Dhananjay all occurences in my textview, and make them clickable as well 
but not @Vijay (as its not in my arraylist)

How to do so?

Comment: [`ClickableSpan`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) is your friend. Plenty of examples available if you do a search.

Comment: becuase its not in my list @Blackbelt

Comment: @MH I did a search, found a lot of examples but not the one I wanted

Comment: oh, if you have your *list* is simple than. And I agree with @MH.. Spannable is the way to go

Comment: Hmm...all the examples I found mentioned some specific prefix or making it clickable through the index.....but not getting the similar thing, I need :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few modifications in [Survivor's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33607892/1479511) worked for me, as per my requirement.

```
  text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

  string += " ";

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(string);
    String[] words = string.split(" ");
    for (final String word : words) {
       if (word.startsWith("@") && mentionsNamesList.contains(word.substring(1))) {
             int lastIndex = 0;

            while(lastIndex != -1){

                lastIndex = string.indexOf(word+" ",lastIndex);

                if(lastIndex != -1){
            ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View textView) {
                    //use word here to make a decision
                }
            };
          ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, lastIndex, lastIndex + word.length(),
                            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

          lastIndex += word.length();
         }
        }
    }
    text.setText(ss);
    text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

The modifications done included the `use of while loop in order to highlight and make clickable every occurrence of the word in the whole textview,instead of only the first one`. The other one was adding space along with the word to highlight, in order to avoid highlighting the substring occurrence within a bigger word. For eg. `test in test123`

Answer (score 1):

I run this code and worked fine for me, check it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView text;
String string = "@Ajay, @Dhananjay, I just had a great fight with @Vijay yesterday";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(string);
    String[] words = string.split(" ");
    for (final String word : words) {
        if (word.startsWith("@") && word.endsWith(",")) {
            ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View textView) {
                    //use word here to make a decision
                }
            };
            ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, string.indexOf(word), string.indexOf(word) + word.length(),
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
    text.setText(ss);
    text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
}
```

[image: See this image]

Comment: I already checked that example somewhere else, but doesn't suit my need

Comment: let me check this one

Comment: you could build on this answer by adding a check if the list contains the word by checking `myList.contains(word)`. Also, I think the check for ',' at the end of the word should be removed since it does not seem relevant?

Comment: it could possible to identify name from string? if yes then i can

Comment: not working.....lets say the text is "Raj_crazy is that good enough Raj Raj". Now, I need to highlight Raj in this, so instead of highlghting the two words in the end, its highlighting Raj from the first word ....'Raj_crazy'

Comment: Also, it should highlight all the occurrences instead of only the first one

Comment: man is there any method to identify person name? then how could you specify to highlight those word with non identifier ?

Comment: no need to identify if its person name or not, just need to check if the words I have in my arraylist, exists in the text or not, if it exists, then should be highlighted wherever it is, and should be clickable